# Trouble with changing classes in stand-alone apps script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

**What I'm doing:** I'm developing an Add-on for Google Sheets, so a stand alone script.  I have 3 separate files - Javascript, CSS & HTML for a sidebar. The sidebar contains a list of options inside select tags.

**Required outcome:** Depending on what is selected in the options, only the associated div should be displayed in the sidebar (the others have display: none). When the select ID is changed, the listSelector function operates to remove the toggle class (so as to hide currently displayed div) and assign toggle to the selected div from the options list.

**Problem I'm experiencing:** I'm having difficulty in getting classes added and removed from HTML elements using JavaScript.

The console shows an error,

> "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelectorAll' of null"

although I'm not sure whether that is related to my problem.  I have replicated the code in JSFiddle and this works as expected:
https://jsfiddle.net/gborchard/1u7p3o2g/

```
<h1>Show the div based on selection</h1>
<select id="someList" onchange="listSelector()">
  <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
  <option value="item1">Item1</option>
  <option value="item2">Item2</option>
  <option value="item3">Item3</option>
</select>

<div id="item1" class="items">Item 1 stuff</div>
<div id="item2" class="items">Item 2 stuff</div>
<div id="item3" class="items">Item 3 stuff</div>
<div id="item4" class="items">Item 4 stuff</div>
<div id="item5" class="items">Item 5 stuff</div>
<div id="item6" class="items">Item 6 stuff</div>

.items {display: none}
.toggle {display: block}

function listSelector() {
  let selected = document.getElementById("someList").value;

  //remove the toggle class from all .items so as to hide existing displayed notes
  document.querySelectorAll('.items').forEach((x) => {
    x.classList.remove("toggle")
  });

  //select the id of the selected item and add the toggle class so as to display intial on the selected item
  let elem = document.getElementById(selected);
  elem.classList.add("toggle");
}
```

I just don't see why the problem is occurring in Apps Script. Any suggestions please?  Even on where to start looking?

Comment: I would recommend you to explain what you are trying to achieve. There is nothing called document in AppScript, its a DOM entity.

Comment: Post updated to better explain what I'm trying to achieve.  I don't understand what is meant by "nothing called document in AppScript, it's a DOM entity". If no document, how to I reference the HTML displayed in the sidebar?

Comment: *have replicated the code in JSFiddle and this works as expected:* Then error is somewhere else. Show rest of the code, calling function and gs files. Explain what you're seeing and what you want to see(literally) instead.

Comment: Thank you.  @TheMaster sent me back to more frustration of yet again, more closely, reviewing my code.  It was a typo and is now functioning as expected. Thank you for your contributions.